# How do I access the old version of Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console

I recently started using Google Search Console for the first time, and for the most part it's been working well. I only have experience with the new version of the console released in 2018. However, some features like the [change of address tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en) are apparently only supported in the old version of Search Console, so I need to access the old console. However, I can't figure out where to go to access it.

How does one access the old legacy version of Google Search Console in 2019?

Comment: https://www.seroundtable.com/google-search-console-defaults-beta-26314.html#:~:text=You%20can%20still%20access%20the,they%20removed%20the%20BETA%20label. : May this helps you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has added the tool 'change of address' in the new search console. So there is no need to use the old search console version.

**Step 1**  - Go to settings followed by tools and click on 'Change of address'
[image: Go to settings followed by tools and click on 'Change of address']
**Step 2** - Select your new site
[image: Select your new site]
Note - You need to have your domain verified on the same Google Search Console Account.

Subsequently, google has also removed the button 'Go to the old version'.
Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

There should be a link in the bottom left corner that says "Go to the old version".

[image]

If that link is missing, it's probably because the domain was added as a "Domain property" instead of as a "URL prefix". Only URL prefix properties can be accessed in the old version of Search Console.

[image]

It's definitely possible to have a site added as both a domain property and URL prefix simultaneously, so if your site is currently validated as a Domain property then all you need to do is Add property and select the URL prefix mode.

Comment: In order to use the [change of address](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en) tool I had to ensure that both my old and new site were added with the URL prefix-style validation.